# Complex analysis books/resources where solutions are difficult to find

Tags: undergraduate-education, reference-books

I am teaching complex analysis for undergraduates using the textbook Complex Variables and Applications, Brown and Churchill. I am looking for resources that I can use to find good problems for homework sets and take-home exams.

The problems in this book are a poor choice for these assessments because there are complete solution manuals available online. I would appreciate any recommendations on where to find decent problems whose solutions are not readily available (or at least harder to find).

Thank you!

Comment: If you have access to a (physical) library, then you might want to look at old textbooks (say, 50 years old or older).  These most likely don't have solution manuals online.

Comment: I've taught the course a few times, I've used Gamelin, Churchill, and before I realized how brutal the problems were, Freitag and Busam. I really like Saff and Snider's text. Anyway, you can see what I have here: http://www.supermath.info/Complex.html it might help.

Comment: Your expectations are unrealistic. Students can post questions on chegg and usually get a full solution within about 60 minutes. For online exams during covid, the only solution I've found is to give many short 30-40 minute exams rather than a few longer exams.

Comment: At this point, any solutions manuals are likely to be on the internet.  There are also solutions for many textbooks where the author has not provided a solutions manual.  A general strategy that has worked well for me is to take exercises from a variety of other sources and rewrite the exercises in my own words.  Simply changing variable and function names can be quite effective at disguising the origin of the problem so that it becomes difficult for students to find the original textbook and solution manual.  You'll still want to monitor Chegg to see if your version of the problem comes up.

Comment: @BenCrowell: I saw your advice on that elsewhere and considered it. Unfortunately, I tested it yesterday (discrete math question, multiple nested quantifiers, justifications required), and the turnaround time to a correct solution was only 10 minutes. (And separately, basically all of my final exam questions were posted and answered on Chegg within the course of the exam.)

Comment: On the other hand, I am currently running a test on a complex analysis question from Lang, and so far it's been a day with no answer posted.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: Of course there are no guarantees, and no countermeasures are 100% effective.

Comment: @BenCrowell: With respect, my point is that I think your estimate may be off by about an order of magnitude (for most course content). If you search online for the question, "How long does Chegg take to get an answer", most students will reply something like, "just a few minutes".

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: It may be that it's very dependent on the type of material. The questions I assign on exams can't really be done in a few minutes. I typically have 2 or 3 questions on a 40-minute exam. But if, e.g., someone is teaching freshman calc and there are problems like differentiating $x^3$, I can certainly imagine it could be quick. My way of verifying that my countermeasures seem effective, for me, is that I check on chegg and only rarely (once last semester) do I find my exam questions on there.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but the other evidence that convinces me of the effectiveness of the approach, in my department, is that other teachers who were giving long exams during covid all found their exams on chegg. Then when they switched to short exams, the problem stopped.

Comment: @BenCrowell Do you have the concern that some students may be disadvantaged by a timed exam during online instruction?

Comment: @an_anagram: The main issue I've seen is that some students have slow internet connections, so video doesn't work well for them. Emailing a picture of their exam paper requires very little bandwidth, so this doesn't seem to be an issue. I do drop the lowest exam (out of 14 exams), on the theory that people's internet connection could go out or something. But realistically that never seems to  have happened.

Comment: Follow-up: The question from the middle of Lang's *Complex Analysis* that I posted to Chegg received an answer (correct, I think) after 2.5 days over the weekend.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins If you received that answer from a student and didn't know it came from Chegg, what grade would you award it? I.e. what was the quality like?

Comment: @shoover: I'm not qualified to speak on that one case because I don't teach or grade complex analysis. For the courses I do teach and the cases I have actually dealt with (e.g., a dozen or so in discrete math), the quality certainly varies -- from perfect, to obviously using terms/notation not in the course, to halfway missing the whole point. It looks like my students can usually tell the same, and avoid or clean up such answers enough to look like our in-class work.

Answer (score 2):

To synthesize some of the remarks given in chat, you can look for very old (or very recent) texts in the hope that there are few or no solutions already available. However, with the rise of online services often providing quick answers to mathematics questions, this may be a lost cause. Effective ways of dealing with this problem might involve different approaches to assessment than the usual assignments and long exams. Ben Crowell suggests frequent short exams as a countermeasure. (Other countermeasures might include using heavily proctored environments or more individualized project-style assessment.)

Comment: Another option is to individuate test questions in some minimal way, such that violators posting to Chegg (e.g.) can be easily identified and sanctioned.